# Non-uniform Deciders for computational indistinguishability

Tags: provable-security

I don't quite understand the notion of a decider having a probability distribution function associated with it, and what it exactly says about the decider. From [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf) on page 3-4 it says

> ...Now, in order to carry
>   out a reduction that breaks some cryptographic primitive or assumption if the ensembles are
>   not
>   computationally indistinguishable, it is necessary for the reduction to know the value of
>   a
>   associated
>   with its given
>   n
>   .  The value
>   a
>   associated with
>   n
>   must therefore be written on the advice tape of
>   the reduction algorithm, making it inherently non uniform.

If our decider is uniform, why can it not associate $a$ with its given value $n$? Is it because its uniform, all possibilities are equally likely and it cannot tell the difference? If someone could maybe clarify for me I would be grateful.

Comment: There is no reason to expect that in general $a$ can be efficiently computed from $n$; why would there be?

Comment: @fkraiem I don't quite understand what you mean. I feel like I am missing something. $a$ and $n$ index our probability ensemble, and $n$ is our security parameter. What does it mean for a decider (an algorithm) to have an associated probability distribution? The sentence "A, an algorithm, is non uniform." does not make sense to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems you think the word "uniform" in "uniform algorithm" refers to a probability distribution. It does not. You should refer to the definitions in your source (or others), but basically a uniform algorithm is a "normal" algorithm, like you have encountered thus far, and a non-uniform algorithm is one with an extra input (the advice string) which depends only on the security parameter.

Comment: Great, you can now answer your own question. :)